# Foreign key as Composite Primary key

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am trying to implement the following PostgreSQL code into php using doctrine2

```
create table tournaments (
id serial primary key,
tournament_name text not null,
start_time timestamp not null,
end_time timestamp not null
);

create table group_slots (
id serial,
tournament_id int references tournaments,
start_time timestamp not null,
end_time timestamp not null,
primary key(id, tournament_id)
);
```

As you can notice there needs to be a `OneToMany` bidirectional relationship between the tournaments and group_slots tables with `tournament_id` being the referenced column. Here is what I have so far:

The `Tournaments` entity:

```
<?php

namespace SportsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SportsBundle\Entity\GroupSlots;

/**
 * Tournaments
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tournaments")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SportsBundle\Repository\TournamentsRepository")
 */
class Tournaments {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tournament_name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $tournament_name;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $start_time;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $end_time;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupSlots", mappedBy="tournament")
     */
    protected $groupslots;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->groupslots = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

The `GroupSlots` entity:

```
<?php

namespace SportsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SportsBundle\Entity\Tournaments;

/**
 * GroupSlots
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="group_slots")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SportsBundle\Repository\GroupSlotsRepository")
 */
class GroupSlots {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $start_time;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $end_time;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tournaments", inversedBy="groupslots")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tournament;

}
```

**Question:**

I cannot use `@ORM\Id` on the refrenced column in the standard way. How do I create the composite primary key including `id` and the referenced column `tournament_id` in the GroupSlots entity?

**EDIT:**

I tried adding `@Id` to the `$tournament` property as demonstrated in the documentation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Here is the updated `GroupSlots` entity:

```
<?php

namespace SportsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use SportsBundle\Entity\Tournaments;

/**
 * GroupSlots
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="group_slots")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SportsBundle\Repository\GroupSlotsRepository")
 */
class GroupSlots {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $start_time;

    /**
     *
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $end_time;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tournaments", inversedBy="groupslots")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tournament_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tournament;

}
```

After which when I run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`, I get the error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                     
  Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity SportsBundle\Entity\GroupSlots
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your composite key seems redundant, because you're already using a serial column in group_slots.  The ID will always be different for every row so each row will be unique regardless of whether the tournament ID is included in the key.  Are you trying to model some restriction such as "No overlapping timeslots for a given tournament"?  If so using the tournament ID in the key won't do it.  You might need to look into another way of enforcing the rule you're trying to model such as a set of check constraints, server side functions or even client side validation.

Comment: @GordonM there is one more table called `groups` that needs to have the same tournament id as `group_slots` so there is a foreign key relationship like `foreign key (group_slot_id, tournament_id) references group_slots(id, tournament_id),`  so the tournament_id and id need to be made either 'unique' or 'primary' in order for it to be a foreign key, so we decided to have it this way

Comment: @GordonM yep, we have check constraints too, no problem on the postgres side, its just that doctrine is not playing nice :)

Comment: I suspect Doctrine simply doesn't support what you want to do.  That's the problem (well one of many but that's another discussion) with ORM.  They rarely support every possible use case that the underlying database can, especially not ones that the developers of the ORM didn't consider.